# AlertDialog inside AlertDialog

Tags: android

I am trying to make a AlertDialog inside AlertDialog , but when I run the code , the secound AlertDialog didnt appear

This is my code , I want to make it like if the user click cancel in the first AlertDialog  , the second AlertDialog will be appear , user can type his name and both the score and the name will pass to ScoreActivity using intern .

```
void generateAlertDialog(final long timeSpent) {
        // 1. Instantiate an AlertDialog.Builder with its constructor
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                GameActivity.this);
        // 2. Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog
        // characteristics
        builder.setMessage(
                "The time stayed in the game is " + timeSpent + "s")
                .setTitle("You Lose!!")
                .setPositiveButton("Replay",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int id) {
                                // User clicked OK button
                                finish();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GameActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int id) {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                        GameActivity.this);
                                builder2.setMessage(
                                        "Please input you name")
                                        .setTitle("Score");
                                final EditText input = new EditText(GameActivity.this);
                                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                                builder2.setView(input);
                                builder2.setPositiveButton("Show Score LIst",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                                int id) {
                                                finish();
                                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScoreActivity.class);
                                                m_Text = input.getText().toString();
                                                intent.putExtra("name", m_Text);
                                                intent.putExtra("result", timeSpent);
                                                startActivity(intent);

                                            }
                                        });
                                builder2.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                                int id) {
                                                finish();
                                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                                startActivity(intent);

                                            }
                                        });

                                // User cancelled the dialog

                            }
                        });

        // 3. Get the AlertDialogfrom create()
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        // 4. Show dialog
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: You try change `AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                        GameActivity.this);` to `AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never call `builder2.create()` or the `show()` method of whatever `builder2.create()` returns. You need to do both of those things right where you have the comment "// User cancelled the dialog".